# CSS Intrinsic Size of Replaced Element

Tags: html, css

I am having a bit of a rough time with [CSS Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3), chapter [4.1. Intrinsic Sizes](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#intrinsic-sizes).

This is the part I am struggling with:

> Since a *block-level* or *inline-level* replaced element whose height **OR**
>   width behaves as `auto` is effectively defined to use its *max-content
>   size* ([CSS2§10.3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width))...

**Background and Question:**

- *Max content size* means `shrink-to-fit` given an *infinite containing block*.
- I.e. no *soft wrap opportunities* should be taken, so the element is as large as it can possibly be (without forcing it larger with properties).
- I cannot see that behavior defined anywhere in [CSS2§10.3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width), for elements where only one dimension is `auto`.
- In fact, not a single part of [CSS2§10.3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width) deals with a scenario where an element only has **one** dimension as `auto`, and has no intrinsic size or intrinsic aspect ratio. (Note the "**OR**" in the block quote above)
- What part of [CSS2§10.3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width) are they referring to?

Comment: Hi @TemaniAfif . This is becoming a (pleasant) habit :). That part does not apply unfortunately, because there both width AND height is presumed to be auto.

Comment: yes that's why I deleted :) .. by the way the AND is included in the OR which make it a bit complex

Answer (score 1):

The width = auto case is covered in 10.3.2. It says:

> ... or if 'width' has a computed value of 'auto', 'height' has some other
>   computed value, and the element does have an intrinsic ratio; then the
>   used value of 'width' is:
>
> ```
> (used height) * (intrinsic ratio)
> ```

The height = auto case is elsewhere, in 10.6.2. It says:

> ... if 'height' has a computed value of 'auto', and the element
>   has an intrinsic ratio then the used value of 'height' is:
>
> ```
> (used width) / (intrinsic ratio)
> ```

That just leaves the case where BOTH height and width are auto, there's no intrinsic dimensions but there is an intrinsic ratio. 10.3.2 covers that by saying:

> If 'height' and 'width' both have computed values of 'auto' and the
>   element has an intrinsic ratio but no intrinsic height or width, then
>   the used value of 'width' is undefined in CSS 2.2.

And the spec is extended in css-sizing 4.1 where it says:

> this specification applies the rules above to the undefined case of a
>   replaced element whose height and width both behave as auto.

Comment: Thank you, Alohci. I struggle seeing how the scaling by "other dimension / intrinsic ratio" is the same as `max-content size`. `max-content size` is supposed to be the largest an element can be, if not constrained in any way by its containing block (which is infinite in size).

Comment: I also have a hard time understanding the paragraph above the one I quoted: "For replaced elements, if the max-content size size would depend on the size of the containing block (as it does for images with an intrinsic aspect ratio but no intrinsic size..)": Why does it not specify that both width/height is auto in that case? That is the only scenario where it stretch fits into its containing block, thus resulting in the problem of containing block being infinite. That paragraph, and the one I have quoted above are confusing. Could they not have sticked with just the two bullets alone?

Comment: @Magnus: Max-content size doesn't mean "as large as possible", it means "as large as the content requires given no other constraints". If the replaced element has an intrinsic height and aspect ratio, then it doesn't need to be taller than that intrinsic height, and its width can always be calculated based on that height and its intrinsic aspect ratio.

Comment: @Magnus: As for your second quote, note that a replaced element with no intrinsic dimensions is not the same thing as a replaced element whose dimensions behave as auto. A replaced element whose dimensions behave as auto *uses* its intrinsic dimensions to calculate its max-content size wrt its containing block. If the containing block has no definite size, and no min-width/height, then it becomes 300px wide and however tall it needs to be given its aspect ratio or 150px tall otherwise.